# Struggling with Scrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am an elderly attempting to learn new-by. This works fine.

```
@implementation MESViewController 
- (void)viewDidLoad { 
[super viewDidLoad];  
self.view= [[QuartzLineView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];} 

-(void)Play{ 
for(int i=0;i<2000;i++){ 
short int  lineno=function result; 
CGRect  myRect=CGRectMake(0,lineno, 1024,lineno+235); 
[self.view setNeedsDisplayInRect:myRect];}
```

However using a scrollview the view does not seem to redraw at all.
Scrollview displays and takes touch input ok.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h 
@interface MESViewController : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate> 
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView; 
@end 

@implementation MESViewController 
- (void)viewDidLoad { 
[super viewDidLoad]; 
self.scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, x, y)]; 
self.scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(x,y); 
UIView *myview= [[QuartzLineView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, x, y)]; 
[self.scrollView addSubview:myview]; 
self.view=self.scrollView;} 

-(void)Play{...as above} 

@implementation QuartzLineView 
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)r{ 
self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, x, y]; 
if (self) { 
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1.0]; 
    self.multipleTouchEnabled = YES; 
} 
return self;}
```

Comment: `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h` is cutoff at the top of the second snippet.  Is this present in the code as well?

Comment: question is unclear, can you please explain what you trying to achieve ?

Comment: The first section of the second code snippet does contain  
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h. I am trying to use a scrollview to display a view with a fixed width of 1024 but variable height. However when i use the above code the scrollview draws correctly initially but does not update/refresh as the -(void)Play function iterates. It does work with the fixed size view in the first code snippet. Thanks

Comment: I suspect this might be a dupe with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609306/using-quartz-to-draw-every-second-via-nstimer-iphone

Comment: If I leave everything the same first with self.view= [[QuartzLineView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]; everything works. If I change it to   UIView *myview= [[QuartzLineView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, x, y)]; 
[self.scrollView addSubview:myview]; 
self.view=self.scrollView; The setNeedsDisplayInRect stops working.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when you set `self.view` to be the scrollview, you are still calling `[self.view setNeedsDisplay]` which will tell the *UIScrollView* that it needs display, and you want to tell the *QuartzLineView* that it needs display.

Saving a reference to the `QuartzLineView`, and calling `setNeedsDisplay` on that should do the trick:

```
@implementation MESViewController{
    // save a reference to the QuartzLineView
    QuartzLineView* lineView;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad { 
    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    self.scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, x, y)]; 
    self.scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(x,y); 

    // saving the reference here
    lineView= [[QuartzLineView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, x, y)]; 
    [self.scrollView addSubview:lineView]; 
    self.view=self.scrollView;
}

-(void)Play{ 
    for(int i=0;i<2000;i++){ 
        short int  lineno=function result; 
        CGRect  myRect=CGRectMake(0,lineno, 1024,lineno+235); 

        // now tell the _lineView_ to setNeedsDisplay, instead of self.view
        [lineView setNeedsDisplayInRect:myRect];
    }
}
```